# How to add security to a EF 5.0 Code First WCF DataService

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, wcf-security

I created several POCO then created a DbContext (FooDbContext) - I then created a DataService class device from DataService< FooDbContext > calll FooDatService. I can access all my data in my silverlight app and if I start a Web Browser I can access it through the URL as expected. Now I want to allow to the DataService only after a successful login.

Comment: Are you using WCF or MVC as your host for your data services?

Comment: I'm guessing WCF as I'm not using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I've blogged on that like 3 years ago

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html

The idea is to reuse the forms cookie to guard your invocations so that only logged in users are allowed to call the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a service authorization manager to your WCF service to put all methods and endpoints of that service under access control, without modifying any of the implementation of the service.

Creating and starting your WCF service:

```
    Uri[] restUris = new Uri[] { new Uri(baseUri, "Api/v1/") };
    // substitute your service host type here. I'm using WCF OData DataServiceHost
    restAPIServiceHost = new DataServiceHost(typeof(API.RestAPIService), restUris);

    var saz = restAPIServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceAuthorizationBehavior>();
    if (saz == null)
    {
        saz = new ServiceAuthorizationBehavior();
        restAPIServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(saz);
    }

    saz.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new MyServiceAuthorizationManager();

    restAPIServiceHost.Open();
```

The above can also be done via web.config magic.

In your MyServiceAuthorizationManager implementation:

```
        public class MyServiceAuthorizationManager: System.ServiceModel.ServiceAuthorizationManager
        {
            public override bool CheckAccess(OperationContext operationContext, ref Message message)
            {
                var reqProp = message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
                var authHeader = new AuthorizationHeader(reqProp.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]);

                bool authorized = // your code to decide if caller is authorized;

                if (!authorized)
                {
                    var webContext = new WebOperationContext(operationContext);
                    webContext.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

                    // optional: give caller hints where to go to login
                    webContext.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add( HttpResponseHeader.WwwAuthenticate, String.Format("Bearer realm=\"{0}\"", baseUri.AbsoluteUri));
                }

                return authorized;
            }
        }
```

This `CheckAccess` method will be called for every request received by your WCF service, before the request is dispatched to the WCF implementation methods.